# Python subprocess.Popen() causing multiple flashing cmd windows when using pyinstaller

Tags: python, subprocess, pyinstaller

I have a program, and I have a feature that calls a process using Popen(). When I call it, multiple cmd windows appear and disappear, including one that appears to the the program that I called that promptly disappears. This only happens on a pyinstaller exe, and the effect seems to be worse on Windows 11. In addition when I close the window that called the other program, the same flashing windows occur.

What is happening here?

Pyinstaller 4.10

Windows 10 and 11

Python 3.10